# C - pseudo shell and concurrency

Tags: c, shell, concurrency

I'm writing a pseudo shell program which creates a child from a parent process. The parent process waits for the child to finish before continuing. My forking code looks something like this:

```
if(fork()==0)
{
     execvp(cmd, args);
}
else
{
     int status = 0;
     wait(&status);
     printf("Child exited with status of %d\n", status);
}
```

But, I want to be able to parse the '&' operator, such that if a user enters it at the end of a command line, the parent won't wait for the child before prompting the user for another command. I added some code to handle this, but I wasn't exactly sure if it's working right. Would it look something like:

```
if(fork()==0)
{
    execvp(cmd, args);
}
else
{
    if(andOp = 1) //boolean to keep track of if '&' was encountered in parsing
    {
        shellFunc();   //main function to prompt user for a cmd line
    }
    int status = 0;
    wait(&status);
    printf("Child exited with status of %d\n", status);
}
```

Does this actually accomplish the concurrency achieved by the regular shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware assignment instead of comparison.

Beware failing to execute a command - `exit(1);` after `execvp()`.

I think I would use:

```
if (andOp == 0)
{
     int status;
     int corpse = wait(&status);
     printf("Child %d exited with status 0x%04X\n", corpse, status);
}
```

That is, I'd only wait if the '&' was missing.

However, with background children dying at random, you need to keep track of the background processes, and in particular, you need to loop on `wait()` until the child you just forked off dies.  So you also need to trap that PID from the `fork()`.

You might want to get fancy and use `waitpid()` after collecting the child you were waiting for, to clean up any other bodies, using the non-blocking option so that if there are no such children, it returns immediately.  You'd still use it in a loop, so that if 6 background jobs all completed, you collect them all.

Alternatively again, you could consider ignoring 'death of child' (SIGCHLD) signals - and letting the system take care of them.  However, a shell typically reports when one of the background jobs completes.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems:

- What if the exec fails?

  - You should kill the child
- What if a signal happens in the parent?

  - wait will exit. You need to detect and re-wait.
- Call the ShellFunc() recursively does not help as there is no real exit stratergy.

  - use int sigaction() to detect child failure on backgrounded tasks.